# What part of speech is NEAR here?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> The lake was near bursting point as it had been raining heavily for weeks.

What part of speech is NEAR here? and WHY?

Comment: Nima, try to learn the formatting. All your questions require editing.

Comment: I am so sorry. OK.

Comment: See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/near

Comment: This sentence doesn't appear to be grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Near is a preposition. Here it describes the level of the water in the lake, so it is said to be near the bursting point. That is, the level of water is near the bursting point.